The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -11850 and domain "AVFoundationErrorDomain"
 <Video
          source={{ uri: item.video }}
          className="w-52 h-72 rounded-[33px] mt-3 bg-white/10"
          resizeMode={ResizeMode.CONTAIN}
          useNativeControls
          shouldPlay
          onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) => {
            if (status.didJustFinish) {
              setPlay(false);
            }
          }}
          onError={(error) => console.error("Video Error:", error)}
        />

Video Error: The server is not correctly configured. - The AVPlayerItem instance has failed with the error code -11850 and domain "AVFoundationErrorDomain".
import { ResizeMode, Video } from "expo-av";
i used expo-av for playing the video but the error is showing like this
I need to solve this issue without the returns of the error

I've came across such issue recently and it was caused by the URL of the video you are providing to the Video component of expo-av.
Basicaly for some reason when you provide an URL to somekind of player with a video, the component does not want to play it but if the URL is directly to .mp4 video for example, then it's working fine (random-short-video.mp4).
You can google for such URL's.
(I only tested this with mp4 format)
